# XPath for all attribute values, not just first?

Tags: xml, xpath, xlrelease

> *Edit:* the issue in my case was caused by a tool that doesn't fully implement the XPath standard. My attempt with `//key@` should have worked (see comments & answer), and the reason it doesn't work is that the tool only shows the first result.

My XML looks like this:

```
<Document id="someIdhere" token="123-456-789" created-by="john_doe" created-at="2020-05-27T10:04:28.244+0000" last-modified-by="jane_doe" last-modified-at="2020-07-30T09:27:59.440+0000">
<somedata/>
<somemoredata/>
<entries>
    <entry key="resourceName">resourceLocation</entry>
    <entry key="foo">bar</entry>
    <entry key="somekey">somevalue</entry>
    <entry key="keyname">keyvalue</entry>
    <entry key="keyname1">value1</entry>
</entries>
<encryptedEntries/>
</Document>
```

I am looking to get the values of all `key` attributes (so 'resourcename','foo', etc) ; not the value of the `<entry>` nodes. There is no way in advance for me to know how many entries there will be, nor what the contents will be.

I have tried the following:

`//@*` -> gives all attributes, not only the `key`
`//entries/@*` -> returns nothing
`//entry@*` -> returns nothing
`//@key` -> returns only the first result
`//entries/key[*]` -> returns nothing
`//entry@key` -> returns nothing
`//entry@key=*` -> returns nothing

I probably tried others as well, but these are what I can remember. If it makes any difference: the XPath is executed by the 'XML Webhook' task in Xebialabs' XLRelease.

Comment: `//@key` is the correct way to get **all** the values, so its not an XPath issue but a tool you're using. Try `//entry/@key` as well

Comment: Thanks @JaSON. `//entry/@key` only returns the first value, so apparently the tool is just being a nuisance. Thanks for your help anyway, and I'll see what I can do about the tool. If you want to make your comment the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I reached out to the company that produces the tool I'm using. Apparently, this is by design: the tool is only able to retrieve one result. So I guess I'm off to find another approach. Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JaSON has already provided you with two viable XPaths [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119053/xpath-how-to-select-all-attribute-values-for-a-specific-attribute#comment113384615_64119053)<sup>1</sup>:

- `//@key` will select all `key` attributes in the document.
- `//entry/@key` will select all `key` attributes of `entry` elements in the document.

You've commented that `//entry/@key` only returns the first value and chalked it up to tool/library noncompliance.  **Realize that there are library APIs that have different calls for returning the first selected item versus returning all selected items.**

Here are explanations for each of the attempts you made:

- `//@*` selects all attributes in the document.
- `//entries/@*` selects nothing because `entries` has no attributes.
- `//entry@*` is syntactically incorrect.
- `//@key` selects all `key` attributes in the document, but see API note above.
- `//entries/key[*]` selects all `key` child elements (of `entries` elements) with at least one child element
- `//entry@key` is syntactically incorrect.
- `//entry@key=*` is syntactically incorrect.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Will upvote his answer if he posts one.</sub>

Comment: I reached out to the company that produces the tool I'm using. Apparently, this is by design: the tool is only able to retrieve one result. So I guess I'm off to find another approach. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but if Jason decides to turn his comment into an answer, I will accept his, considering he was first.